# Convert string to HEX characters

Tags: string, python-2.7, hex

I have the following short code:

```
import socket
from sys import *

host = "10.10.10.10"
port = 7142
buf  = 1024

tcpSock = socket.socket()
tcpSock.settimeout(100)
tcpSock.connect((host,port))

## Send message
data ='\x01\x30\x41\x30\x41\x30\x36\x02\x30\x31\x44\x36\x03\x74\x0d'
if(tcpSock.send(data)):    
    print "Sending message:",data
data = tcpSock.recv(4096) 
tcpSock.close()

print "Received message:", data
#print "Received message:", data.strip().decode("hex")
```

the output been:

*Sending message: ☺0A0A06☻01D6♥t*

*Received message: ☺00AB12☻0200D60000040001♥t*

Where I am stuck on is how to decode the "received message" back from the server to HEX characters

Thanks
Alexis

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try this code

```
import binascii
mytext='☺00AB12☻0200D60000040001♥t'
print binascii.hexlify(mytext)
```

I've received this output

```
3f3030414231323f303230304436303030303034303030313f74
```